# Most efficient way to vstack two 5GB arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, append

I have two numpy array each 5 gig size and want to vstack. It requires 10 gig memory to do this.

I'm getting out of memory errors when attempting to vstack the arrays. Is there a more efficient way to stack the two arrays than just keeping two copies of them in memory?

What about if I make them both list than append and than convert the numpy array?

Comment: The end result will still be 10 gig, regardless of how it's constructed?

Comment: How do you create data? Many of numpy's function have 'out' argument. When you create those 5g arrays you can require numpy to use a slice of preallocated 10gb buffer. Please provide more details